# What's the shell script meaning?

Tags: shell

I am a newer in shell script, following is a shell script:

```
$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -Dpid=MyJava \
    -Xms${HEAP_MIN}m -Xmx${HEAP_MAX}m -cp ${CPG_CLASSPATH} \
    -Dconfig=${CFG_FILE} \
    -Dcom.test.eps.configpath=${my_config}/ \
    -Dcom.test.eps.rt.config=${my_config}/ \
    -Dlog4j.configuration=file:///${my_config}/log4j.properties.ewf.rt \
    com.test.MyJava &
```

Can anyone tell me the code meaning of every line above?

Comment: If you're new in shell script, then pick something easier to learn from. Crawl before you go hang gliding.

Comment: In his defense I would guess If hes dealing with command lines like this he doing a job in a enterprise enviornment, and he doesnt get to pick when and what he learns, hes just has got to get his job done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$JAVA_HOME/bin/java` — invokes the JRE binary located at the bin path of the folder designated by the `$JAVA_HOME` variable set in the current user's enviornment. That is, it runs Java, specifically the version pointed at by JAVA_HOME.

The trailing `\`s are escape charecters which escape the newline at the end of the line. Normally in a shell program a newline at the end of the line tells the shell that you're done with the command and it can interpret it now. Ending a line with `\` tells the shell that the command will actually continue on the next line, i.e. this is all one command.

`-Dpid=myJava` — sets a system property for the jre named pid with value myJava. Java programs can basically ask, `getProperty("pid")` at runtime and it will return `"myJava"` and then choose its behavior appropriately, this is a way of configuring the programs the the JRE runs.

`-Xms${HEAP_MIN}m` — sets javas min heap size to value in `${HEAP_MIN}` env var. The heap size is how much memory the jre sets aside to store its stack trace.

`-Xmx${HEAP_MAX}m` — sets Java's max heap size to value in `${HEAP_MAX}` env var.

`-cp ${CPG_CLASSPATH}` — sets the Java classpath to the value in the `${CPG_CLASSPATH}` env var.

`-Dconfig=${CFG_FILE}` — sets a system property for the JRE named config with value ${CFG_FILE}.

`-Dcom.test.eps.configpath=${my_config}/` — sets a system property for the JRE named `com.test.eps.configpath` with value `${my_config}`.

`-Dcom.test.eps.rt.config=${my_config}/` — sets a system property for the JRE named `com.test.eps.rt.config` with value `${my_config}`.

`-Dlog4j.configuration=file:///${my_config}/log4j.properties.ewf.rt` — sets a system property for the JRE named log4j.configuration with value `file:///${my_config}/log4j.properties.ewf.rt`.

`com.test.MyJava` is a Java class essentially located on the classpath at `com/test/MyJava.class` which presumably has a `main` function. After the JRE initializes with all of the previous configurations set, it will run this class and run its main function.

`&` tells the OS to run this command in its own process and not to wait for it to return before the cli gives control back to the user. It's basically telling the OS to run this program in a process separate from the one which is running your shell.

Comment: +1: Good explanation of the Java side of the script — what the arguments mean to the JVM.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your on a unix based system, check this out:

http://www.manpagez.com/man/1/java/

That is complicated, so maybe you should learn the basics of shell scripting first:

http://www.freeos.com/guides/lsst/

Answer (score 1):

As shell goes, there is nothing intrinsically complex there; there is, however, an awful lot of the same sort of stuff over and over.

At the highest level, it is a single command.  The backslashes at the ends of the lines continue the command with the information on the next line.  It invokes the JVM (Java Virtual Machine, which is the key component of the JRE, Java Runtime Environment) found in the directory `$JAVA_HOME/bin`, where `$JAVA_HOME` is (I trust you recognize), a shell variable; indeed, it should be an environment variable.  The JVM is invoked with 10 arguments (unless I've miscounted again), and is run in the background (that's the `&` at the end).  That means the shell script launches the JVM and does not wait for it to complete.

Some of the arguments also contain the expanded form of shell variables, some of which may be environment variables (you cannot tell definitively which variables are environment variables simply by looking at them, but conventionally, environment variables are all upper-case, like `$JAVA_HOME`).  The alternative notation `${HEAP_MAX}` expands a variable `HEAP_MAX`, just as `$HEAP_MAX` does.  However, in that argument, you cannot (sensibly) write:

```
-Xmx$HEAP_MAXm   # Wrong (in this context)
```

because that looks for a variable `$HEAP_MAXm`; you use the braces to delimit the name of the variable.  There are also a lot of other things you can do with the name in braces, such as `${JAVA_HOME:?}` which says that if `$JAVA_HOME` is not set, generate an error message and stop the script.  See the manual for 'Parameter Expansion'.

For the meanings of the arguments to the JVM, you'll need to look at the man page.  As an exercise in shell, though, the other arguments are all variations on what has been discussed already, using different variables to identify the locations of files needed by the JVM or the program it is running.